# Mathematics Mod Function

Tags: matlab, math, rsa, wolframalpha

I would love if someone can try to explain the difference between the two equations below and why they equal different values but from what i can see are the same.

[image: 23^-1 mod 4169]

[image: mod(23^-1, 4169)]

I am using MATLAB to try to compute the first equation shown, however, I am getting the result of the second.

```
d = mod(23^-1, 4169)
RESULT: 0.0435
SHOULD BE: 3444
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: If `x^-1 = y`, that means `x * y = 1`. In conventional arithmetic, this means that `y = 1/x` (the first result). In modular arithmetic (commonly used in cryptography), this means "find a number `y`, such that when multiplied by `x`, the result is 1 (with the specified divisor e.g. 4169)". Wolfram|Alpha's natural language processing works this out in a manner that suits you - MATLAB cannot. Instead, you have to compute this yourself - [try this](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81859-how-to-write-matlab-code-for-modular-multiplicative-inverse-in-cryptography).

Comment: heh how could `(23^-1) mod 4169` be greater than one? The only possibilities I can think of is that the result is reciprocal in some RING like GF4169 ... but that is not normal arithmetics anymore or `-1` is handled as unsigned int or `^` is handled as XOR

Comment: `23 * 3444 = 79212 =  19 * 4169 + 1 = 1 (mod 4169)`

Comment: @magnesium reciprocal in RING it is then (+1 thx for clarifying) ... the other result use normal arithmetics ...

Comment: to obtain integer result in RING you have to force MATLAB to do so ... use some kind of reduction like Montgomery  or do a loop and "bruteforce" search for it your self ... havent use MATLAB for decades and back then it was not very well suited for integer computations related to cryptography...